# NestJS GraphQL inconsistent autoSchemaFile and service sql

Tags: graphql, apollo, nestjs-gateways, nestjs-graphql

I'm using nestJS with ApolloFederationDriver. I also add some prefix with transformSchema option. The issue is that in sdl I can't see that prefix, but in the autoSchemaFile he is. It is a problem, because I can't create connection between this microservice and Gateway.

```
 @Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      autoSchemaFile: 'src/graphql/schema.gql',
      driver: ApolloFederationDriver,
      plugins: [
        ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault(),
        ApolloServerPluginInlineTraceDisabled(),
      ],
      sortSchema: true,
      transformSchema: <some_transforms>,
      transformAutoSchemaFile: true,
    }),
  ],
})
```

Example from the schema.gql file

```
type Query {
  prefix_getSomeData(filter: prefix_FilterInput)
}
```

And the same query in the sdl(*query **ApolloGetServiceDefinition** { _service { sdl } }*)

```
type Query {
  getSomeData(filter: FilterInput)
}
```

How I can add prefix to the sdl file?